# jquery click listener on remote javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, event-listener

I have a simple link:

```
<a href="#" id="test">Test Link</a>
```

I want to get an alert whenever this link is pressed, so I add:

```
<script>
$('#test').click(function() { alert('clicked!'); } );
</script>
```

and it works fine, but when i move this code to a remote javascript file, it doesn't work..

any idea why?

I've also tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').click(function() { alert('clicked!'); });
});
```

Comment: How are you referencing the external file?

Comment: make sur you have include jquery first, second `$document.ready...`, third your html. Or give more of your code for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example, using the `ready` function, should be working. Your first example should also work provided you include the script *below* the element with the ID "test" (the element has to already exist when your script runs, since you're not waiting for DOM ready). In both cases, your script must be included *below* (after) the jQuery script.

[Example when you *don't* use `ready`](http://jsbin.com/ufoxe3)

[Example when you *do* use `ready`](http://jsbin.com/ufoxe3/2)

I'd check that your external file is actually getting loaded (look for 404 errors in the browser console).

---

**Update**: From your comment below, the problem is that the "test" element doesn't exist when you're trying to hook up the handler. `click` only sets up the handler on the element if it *already* exists. If you're creating the element later, you have three options (two of which are really the same):

1. Use the code you already have, but run it after you've created the element (e.g., in the [`success` callback of the ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you're making).
2. Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), which basically hooks the `click` event document-wide and then checks to see if the element you tell it ("#test", in this case) was clicked.
3. Use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the appropriate container (the element within which you're adding "test"). `delegate` is a more targeted version of `live`.

`live` and `delegate` are both examples of a technique called *event delegation*, which jQuery makes easy for you by providing those methods.

See the links for further information and examples, but for example, suppose you're going to be adding the "test" element to an element with the ID "target". You'd use `delegate` like this:

```
$("#target").delegate("#test", "click", function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

That hooks the `click` event on "target", but *acts* a lot like you've just magically hooked it on "test" as soon as "test" was added. Within your handler, `this` refers to the "test" element just as with `click`.

Comment: ok, i've done more testing and found the problem (i think). the `#test` element is loaded using ajax, so maybe because it only loads after the DOM is ready, it has no listeners? what do you think? and if it is the problem, what can i do to create listeners to DOM elements that gets loaded using Ajax?